# Confused about discrepancy between single exponential smoothing equation

Tags: statistics, time-series

Here are the two references I am looking at for this equation:

https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc432.htm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing

One says $$S_{t+1} = \alpha y_t + (1 - \alpha)S_t,$$
And the other says $$s_{t} = \alpha x_t + (1 - \alpha)s_{t-1}.$$

If you change the indices on any one of the equations to make it match the other, say for example if I change the second one I listed to match the first one:

$$s_{t+1} = \alpha x_{t+1} + (1 - \alpha)s_{t},$$

then change the corresponding letters to match (capitalizing the '$S$' and changing $x$ into $y$):

$$S_{t+1} = \alpha y_{t+1} + (1 - \alpha)S_{t},$$

you can see the two equations do not match with the first of the two terms on the right side.

I am not sure which one is the correct equation to learn since I am learning this on my own.

Comment: The first is a *forecast* and so uses current and past data to look forward a step.  The second is smoothing up to *now*.  If $x_t =y_t$ then $S_{t+1}=s_t$ so they are essentially the same and are both exponential smoothing.

Comment: @Henry I'm not sure I understanding "smoothing up to now". Does that mean we are not forecasting anything? How can the expected value at $t$ depend on the observed value at $t$? To me, that seems like asking: if I know I have exactly one cookie in my hand right now, let me try to figure out how many cookies I have in my hand right now. We already know the observed value, but we're still trying to forecast what we already know, and not the future? This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It is what smoothing do: I have a sample with noise, which is the *real* value without noise? I recover it estimating the error from all the observations.